# characters wont display correct with Quasar Framework together with i18n

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quasar-framework, vue-i18n

Im using [i18n](https://quasar.dev/options/app-internationalization) together with [Quasar Framework](https://quasar.dev/). It works great but I have some problems with some special characters in certain languages when grabbing text from my own definations.

I got this in i18n.js in my boot:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import VueI18n from "vue-i18n";

import messages from "src/i18n";

Vue.use(VueI18n);

const i18n = new VueI18n({
  locale: "en-us",
  fallbackLocale: "en-us",
  messages,
});

export default ({ app }) => {
  // Set i18n instance on app
  app.i18n = i18n;
};

// if you need to import it from
// other files, then:
export { i18n };
```

and use it in template like this:

```
<template>
...
 <div>{{ $t('hello') }}</div>
...
```

and in my bootfile

```
boot: ["i18n"],
framework: {
  iconSet: "material-icons", // Quasar icon set
  lang: "en-us", // Quasar language pack
```

Here is the setup in my language component:

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      toggleSMenu: false,
      myData: ["one", "two"],

      lang: this.$i18n.locale,
      langOptions: [
        { value: "en-us", label: "EN" },
        { value: "nl", label: "NL" }
      ]
    };
  },
```

When I change to Dutch (NL) some caracters wont display correctly. How can I add support for dutch letters?

Comment: Problem is probably in the encoding of the file with the translations. Check your editor and make sure the file is saved with `utf-8` encoding...

Comment: I actually checked that. Just in case i opened it and saved it again with utf-8 but no difference

Comment: ok, so directly in the editor the problematic characters are displaying ok ? so maybe font issue ? Do you have `<meta charset="UTF-8">` in your `index.html` ?

Comment: Yes it is there. It is not unlikely a font issue ... it is a non standard font. How can i check this?